# Oracle SQL Query:Find out which year total sales amount is maximum

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, max

***my working table, Table name: sales***

**Here Is MY TABLE, [sl_no is primary key] table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE  SALES 
  ( SL_NO NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, REGION VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL, 
    MONTH VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, YEAR NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    SALES_AMOUNT NUMBER NOT NULL )
```

**and here is table data:**

```
SQL> select * from sales;

     SL_NO REGION     MONTH                      YEAR SALES_AMOUNT
---------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- ------------
         1 east       december                   2011       750000
         2 east       august                     2011       800000
         3 west       january                    2012       640000
         5 east       march                      2012      1200000
         6 west       february                   2011       580000
         4 west       april                      2011       555000

6 rows selected.
```

I have tried this query to view total sales amount of those[2011,2012] year;

```
 SELECT year, SUM(sales_amount) FROM sales GROUP BY year;

      YEAR SUM(SALES_AMOUNT)
---------- -----------------
      2011           2685000
      2012           1840000
```

**MY GOAL:> I want to find out the year of maximum sales amount.**
I tried this,and work perfectly...but when ***i want to display that year also***, it gives an Error.

```
SQL> select  max(sum(sales_amount)) from sales group by year;

MAX(SUM(SALES_AMOUNT))
----------------------
               2685000

SQL> select year, max(sum(sales_amount)) from sales group by year;
select year, max(sum(sales_amount)) from sales group by year
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

**Extra addition: if multiple rows have same value means....when sales amount of both year[2011,2012] remain same, Then....**

plZ help me to Solve this problem.

Comment: i used this query and it works and it also simplest way to display 1st row.BUT it is not works when sales amount of both year[2011,2012] remain same...  
 **select * from (select year, sum(sales_amount) from sales group by year order by sum(sales_amount) desc) where rownum = 1;**

Comment: After long time..Here is my Query where multiple row can select `SELECT year,MAX(total_sale) as max_total FROM(SELECT year,SUM(sales_amount) AS total_sale FROM sales GROUP BY year) GROUP BY year HAVING MAX(total_sale)=(SELECT MAX(total_sale) FROM(SELECT SUM(sales_amount) AS total_sale FROM sales GROUP BY year));` i hope it will work.This should work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my Query where multiple row can select

```
SELECT year,MAX(total_sale) as max_total
FROM 
    (SELECT year,SUM(sales_amount) AS total_sale FROM sales GROUP BY year)
GROUP BY 
    year HAVING MAX(total_sale) = 
           (SELECT MAX(total_sale) FROM (SELECT SUM(sales_amount) AS total_sale FROM sales GROUP BY year));
```

Answer (score 0):

Following select should do what you need (untested, do not have Oracle at home):

```
    select year, total
      from (
            select year, sum(sales_amount) total
              from sales
             group by year
           )
     where total = (select max(total_amount)
                     from (
                           select year, sum(sales_amount) total_amount
                             from sales
                            group by year                    
                          ))
```

Take in account, though, that it might give you different years in each execution if two of them have exactly the same total amount. You might want to include some more conditions to avoid this.

Comment: i have **SQL Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0**. Your suggestion is not working.... it gives an Error:   " ERROR at line 1: ORA-00936: missing expression  "

Comment: The problem was I forgot to rename the `SUM`column to `total` in the first subselect. I will correct it so anybody checking this question can decide whether to use my answer or Ravi's one. Both are semantically equivalent

Comment: @pal: the version of SQL*Plus (the "client") is irrelevant, if at all you need to supply the version of the Oracle **server**

Comment: @pal, two parentheses were missing. It is corrected and tested now (today I have access to Oracle again)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
with yr_agg as (
  select year, sum(sales_amount) as total
  from sales
  group by year
)
select year, total as max_total
from yr_agg
where total = (select max(total)
               from yr_agg);
```

Comment: is it possible,if sales amount of both year[2011,2012] remain same, then is it work ??

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to order the results and take the first row:

```
select year, sales_amount
from (SELECT year, SUM(sales_amount) as sales_amount
      FROM sales
      GROUP BY year
      order by sum(sales_amount) desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

EDIT:

If you need to display all the matching rows (which isn't mentioned in the question), I would suggest using the `dense_rank()` analytic function:

```
select year, sales_amount
from (SELECT year, SUM(sales_amount) as sales_amount,
             dense_rank(over order by SUM(sales_amount) desc) as seqnum
      FROM sales
      GROUP BY year
      order by sum(sales_amount) desc
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or, you might like the `max()` version instead:

```
select year, sales_amount
from (SELECT year, SUM(sales_amount) as sales_amount,
             max(sum(sales_amount)) over () as maxsa
      FROM sales
      GROUP BY year
      order by sum(sales_amount) desc
     ) t
where sales_amount = maxsa;
```

Comment: sorry, it gives an Error.
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00935: group function is nested too deeply

Comment: I have tried this,but i think this is wrong way.....through it we can display 1st row which is large one. But if sales amount of both year[2011,2012] remain same, then only one is displayed. **We need to display all rows.**

Comment: i used this query which properly works and it also simplest way.  **select * from (select year, sum(sales_amount) from sales group by year order by sum(sales_amount) desc) where rownum = 1;**

Comment: SORRY give an Error. **select year, sales_amount
from (SELECT year, SUM(sales_amount), max(sum(sales_amount)) over () as maxsa ....**,
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "SALES_AMOUNT": invalid identifier

Comment: @pal . . . I had accidentally deleted the column alias.